# Simple loop, not so simple Error

Tags: c#, for-loop

I´m getting an error that is driving me crazy... i can´t find what is wrong with this code, any one will be so kind to give me some assistance?

---

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        for(int i = args[0].Length; i >= 1; i--){
            Console.WriteLine(args[0].Substring(i, 1));
        }
    }
}
```

A run example should be like: program.exe 6735

And the output will looks like:

5

3

7

6

So far the only thing i am getting is:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex +
>   length > this.length Parameter name: length   at
>   System.String.Substring (Int32 startIndex, Int32 length) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for(int i = args[0].Length; i >= 1; i--)`

should be

`for(int i = args[0].Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: Thank you very much! :) that was just THE PERFECT solution!.What i didn´t realized is that args[0].Length in the case of 12345 is 5 but the index of each number goes from 0 to 4 not from 1 to 5!, should had seen that before

Answer (score 1):

`args[0].Length` is the length of your string. Since strings are `0` indexed, the length is one index past the last character in the string.

If you want to loop in reverse through a string, you should start your iterator at `Length - 1`.

Comment: args[0].Length is not the length of the array, is the length of the element contained at the index 0 of the array. Any way, thank you for the response.

Comment: @AcidRod75 You're right, sorry. It's the length of the string, not array, contained in "args[0]". I'll edit my answer appropriately.